# Facebook friends online

Tags: facebook

The question is:
need a php script put on cron - it will mail me facebook user friends status (online or not). Found two variants:
1. using fql query $result = $facebook->api(array(
'query' => "SELECT name,online_presence FROM user WHERE uid IN (
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())",
'method' => 'fql.query'));
2. using xmpp. Logging to jabber facebook chat and get user presence from it.

But the question is - who to make it using only users facebook login and password (without secret facebook key, application id).
Just define the user name, password and the script will fetch the friends status.

Comment: That may be a violation of facebooks TOS...  You should be interfacting to facebook with App credentials...  Also it probably would be fairly simple with the new Graph API...

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you're trying to do without using the API (FQL or Graph) or XMPP (Jabber) would be to try and act like a browser to scrape facebook pages (which technically is against their TOS).

Comment: The idea is to make a script suitable for every user - just change the name and password. No id and key. So it can work from cron - mail me the status of the defined users.

Comment: It still is a violation of facebook TOS... And the same thing could be acomplished through the API... Actually it is easier and better through the API.. You are essentially asking people to fork over their facebook usernames and passwords and storing them in a database/datafile... Not that safe...  With the API, the users choose to grant your application premission ... Then your app acts on their behalf...          So stick with the API and dont snipe passwords